# How to use for loop to perform Pearson correlation in r

Tags: r, for-loop, pearson-correlation, pearson

I have a dataset 673 x 232. I want to use for loop to perform Pearson correlation and save p-value and estimate.
My code is

```
vec_lipid <- colnames(df3[,9:232])
df4 <- data.frame(vec_lipid)
df4$p.value <- "0"
df4$estimate <- "0"

for (i in length(vec_lipid)) {
  cortest[i] <- cor.test(df3$CSF_Ab42, df3$vec_lipid[i], method = "pearson")
  df4[i,2] <- cortest[i]$p.value
  df4[i,3] <- cortest[i]$estimate
  i = i+1
  }
```

However it doesn't work. Can you please help to adjust the code?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please provide data, use `dput(head(df3))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly, you are only interested in the correlation between columns 9 to 232 and CSF_Ab42. Then you could use following code based on `sapply`, avoiding the use of a loop.

```r
df4 <- sapply(df3[,-1:-8], \(x) {
  ct <- cor.test(df3$CSF_Ab42, x)
  unlist(ct[c("estimate","p.value")])
}) |> t() |> as.data.frame()
```

The df3 rownames are the corresponding column names of df3, for which the correlation with CSF_Ab42 was computed. If you want to put it inside a column simply add: `df4$lipid <- rownames(df4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might start by chunking that problem into smaller pieces, make sure *everything* works as you expect and only then combine it all together. For example that loop only gets to run once because `length(vec_lipid)` returns a single value; `df3$vec_lipid[i]` will not work, though `df3[[vec_lipid[i]]]` should; for `cortest[i] <- ...` to work, `cortest` must be created first; and generally you don't want to modify for-loop control variables with something like `i = i+1`

Using iris dataset as an example, a slight variation of the previous answer might look like this:

```r
head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

iris[2:4] |>
  lapply(cor.test, iris$Sepal.Length) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  subset(select = c(estimate, p.value))
#>              estimate   p.value     
#> Sepal.Width  -0.1175698 0.1518983   
#> Petal.Length 0.8717538  1.038667e-47
#> Petal.Width  0.8179411  2.325498e-37
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>